# Minimum absolute difference between elements in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider two 1d numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([-43, 21, 4, 6, -1, 22, 8])
Y = np.array([13, 5, -12, 0])
```

I want to find the value(s) from `X` that have the **minimum absolute difference** with the value(s) from `Y`.  In the example shown, the minimum absolute difference is 1, given by `[[4, 5], [6, 5], [-1, 0]]`.  There are lots of resources on this site about finding minimum element of arrays, but that's not what I'm after.

For the present question, both starting arrays are 1d, though their sizes may differ.   I'd also be interested, though, on tips about how to proceed if the starting arrays had different shapes.  Is it simply a matter of flattening both then proceeding as before?

Comment: You might want to include `[-1,0]` in your example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the absolute distance array and then find the minimum in that array. This method works for different `X` and `Y` lengths. If they are multi-dimensional, simply flatten them first (using `X.flatten()`, ...) and apply this solution to the flattened arrays:

If you want **ALL pairs with minimum absolute distance**:

```
#absolute distance between X and Y
dist = np.abs(X[:,None]-Y)
#elements of X with minimum absolute distance
X[np.where(dist==dist.min())[0]]    
#corresponding elements of Y with absolute distance
Y[np.where(dist==dist.min())[1]]
```

output:

```
[ 4  6 -1]
[5 5 0]
```

And you want them in a single array format:

```
idx = np.where(dist==dist.min())
np.stack((X[idx[0]], Y[idx[1]])).T

[[ 4  5]
 [ 6  5]
 [-1  0]]
```

If you want **the first occurrence of minimum absolute distance** with faster solution:

```
X[dist.argmin()//Y.size]
Y[dist.argmin()//X.size]
```

or equally another solution (I think would be faster):

```
idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(dist), dist.shape)
X[idx[0]]
Y[idx[1]]
```

output:

```
4
5
```

Note: Another way of getting the absolute distance array is:

```
dist = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(X,Y))
```

Comment: I really like the X[dist.argmin()//Y.size] solution - it's super efficient and fast.

Comment: @user109387 If you only need the first occurrence, I just added a solution that I think is even faster (if you want the pair. Otherwise the previous one should be about the same performance). Please check it out if performance matters to you. Thank you.